# Looping over emails to extract attachments to multiple locations

Tags: python, loops, email

I am writing a piece of code to try to download the zipped attachment from 2 separate emails. The email module I am using is called [Imbox](https://pypi.org/project/imbox/).

The emails are from an external source and have the same sender address and subject. The name of the attachment is also the same (eg. `'report_10_november.zip'`).  The aim is to download the attachment from the 1st email and save to the first location in the path_list and then save the attachment from the second email in the second path_list location.

As the emails are external I am not able to change any of the conditions mentioned.

```
path_list = ['c:/Users/../Trades1/', 'c:/Users/../Trades2/']

mail = Imbox(host, username=username, password=password, ssl=True, ssl_context=None, 
             starttls=False)
messages = mail.messages(folder='Inbox', subject='Your requested Daily-trade report is 
       attached') # defaults to inbox

for i in range(len(path_list)):
    for (uid, message) in messages:
       mail.mark_seen(uid) # optional, mark message as read

       for idx, attachment in enumerate(message.attachments):
           try:
      
               att_fn = attachment.get('filename')
               download_path = path_list[i]+'Trades.zip'
               with open(download_path, "wb") as fp:
                   fp.write(attachment.get('content').read())
    
           except:
               print(traceback.format_exc())
```

This code extracts an attachment from one of the emails and writes to both locations meaning my attempt to loop over the 2 messages in `messages` is incorrect.  It seems to be only reading the first email.

I have tried to create a list with the attachment filenames and then download those but in this case only one of the zip locations downloads.

I have checked that `messages` does contain the 2 emails from my `Inbox`. I have also searched StackOverflow for a solution but without success - much of the code here I have found on this site.

Comment: You appear to be using some third-party email module but have not identified which one it is. `Inbox` is misspelled in your code and the indentation is inconsistent. I suggest you [edit] your question and fix these flaws.

Comment: The `download_path = path_list[i]+'Trades.zip'` is going to set `download_path` to the same thing for each `attachment` in `message.attachments` because `i` doesn't change inside the `for idx, attachment in enumerate(message.attachments):` loop.

Comment: the email module I am using  to access the email is called Imbox, so there is no misspelling: https://pypi.org/project/imbox/. As I state the text, both the email messages are being called so I do not see this as the problem, but instead that my loops are somehow incorrect

Comment: If you had mention the module in your question I might not have thought you had misspelled the name. As I mentioned, the `download_path` is going to be the same for each attachment inside that innermost `for` loop. This means if there are multiple attachments, only that last one written will be what ends up in the `path_list[i]+'Trades.zip'` file (because `i` is the same for each one).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and was in line with what I was thinking.  However, I am unable to work out how to link them so that each attachment gets copied to the different locations? Do you have any hints as to how to go about doing that?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what's in `path_list`, but something like `path_list[i]+'Trades'+str(idx)+'.zip'` would put each attachment in a file with a slightly different name. You might also be able to name each attachment file `path_list[i]+att_fn`.